# Why did Drogon do this?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In S08E06 of *Game of Thrones*, we see Drogon burn down the

> Iron Throne.

Why did he do that? Did he grow a conscience and see that it was a source of evil?

Comment: There is a theory going around which I think is a joke so posting as a comment. Drogon saw the knife in Dany & assumed she went to sit in the chair made of knives & got herself stabbed. So he took revenge by melting it

Comment: Was it the writers saying "we really, really aren't going to make any more of this"?

Comment: @KharoBangdo That is not a joke. I even thought that is the reason for burning the iron throne

Comment: Drogon knew Bran Stark has his own chair designed. So, there's no need of iron throne. So he burnt it. ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lazy writing and symbolism (Daeron explained the symbolism in his [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/100894/59364)).

A couple of in-universe explanations:

1. He was going to incinerate Jon but at the last second decided against it. He already generated the fire and had to release it, the Iron Throne was simply in the direction of his fire breath by coincidence.
2. Dragons are very smart, he realized that his mother died because she was chasing the Throne and burned it in rage.

## Edit

---

After watching it again there were two separate fire breaths, Drogon first released the fire he was going to burn Jon with without harming the Irone Throne and then destroyed the throne on purpose with a separate fire breath.

This means the first option is wrong and leaves only the second.

Comment: Or your first line.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you just edited it to remove the first option.

Comment: Indeed. If you think part of the answer is no longer valid, you should edit it to keep only the valid/correct parts. The answer should stand as if it were always the best version of itself.

Comment: There is no indication that he wanted to incinerate Jon at all. He was just shown furious and we expected that he might burn Jon(because we knew what he did, but Drogon did not). It is not clear if it was his intent at all.

Comment: @KamiKaze It sure as hell looked like it. He moved towards Jon, looked directly at him, and started to generate fire. At the same moment Jon also looked like he knows he's going to be incinerated, shame you weren't there to tell him there was no indication.

Comment: It was the generated expectation. But I see no indication that he really decided to not do it in the last second.

Answer (score 24):

## It symbolized the end of monarchy.

Here's a nice little summary.

> The red-tinted dragon then unleashes a powerful stream of flame aimed right at the very thing that has been such a point of contention since season one. He succeeds in melting all the swords down to a bubbling, molten puddle. Just as Tyrion says later on in the episode when discussing why Bran would make a good king — "Sons of kings can be cruel and stupid as you well know . . . that is the wheel our Queen wanted to break" — Drogon succeeds in symbolically erasing the idea of a monarchy, whether purposefully or not.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[The Meaning Behind Drogon's Fiery Symbolic Gesture in the Game of Thrones Finale - PopSugar](https://www.popsugar.com/entertainment/Why-Did-Drogon-Burn-Iron-Throne-46175683)</sub>

As to whether or not Monarchy is actually gone, in the quote above it is to be interpreted that an elective monarchy is not a monarchy. Here is Tyrion's quote.

> (Tyrion) From now on, rulers will not be born.
>   They will be chosen on this spot by the lords and ladies of Westeros to serve the realm.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>Game Of Thrones, Season 8, Episode  8 (The Iron Throne)</sub>

---

<sub>Speculation:

As far as official statements go, there has been no explanation as to Drogon's intentions in melting it. It looked to me like he was trying to send Jon a message; if Dany couldn't have the throne, no one could.</sub>

Comment: An elective monarchy is still a monarchy.

Comment: You described what he did and what it symbolizes, not why he did it.

Comment: @Charles It would be better to say "hereditary monarchy", yes. But in normal speech, "monarchy" and "hereditary monarchy" are essentially synonymous.

Comment: @josh1978, he did it because the Script says so. All that happened this season happened for this reason only. Because most of events have no meaning in-universe.

Comment: How much did Tyrion know about the situation at that point? He was a prisoner the whole time, right?

Answer (score 3):

[Dareon's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/100894/40263) nails it in terms of symbolism.  My guess on an in-universe answer is that Drogon has spent so much time linked to Dany, he knows the throne was the object that led her to her death.  (Pure speculation, mind you!)

Answer (score 2):

I watched this most emotional scene of the last season and in my opinion the reason is: he did not harm Jon, instead he burnt the Iron Throne because he knew that this throne is the reason behind his mother's death. If he didn't know, then he would have burnt Jon.

The writer wants to tell the love of child for his mother. No matter that Drogon is an animal; the love for the mother is same.

And the second case is: he knew his mother loved Jon, so he didn't harm him because Dany would not  allowed him, if she  was  alive.

Answer (score 2):

Initially Drogon had the full intention to incinerate Jon as he felt the pain his mother did in his heart. The unexpected bitter reality made him cry and he wanted to turn the reason and the person behind it to ashes. Still he did not harm Jon, but he did burn the Iron Throne because he knew it was the throne Dany had been running after her whole life and Drogon knew how much the throne meant to her but when Drogon saw her dead, he burned the throne intentionally as he thought, if Dany could not sit in it, no one ever will.

The love of child for his mother is shown. His love for his mother is very much like own.
After his brothers' death, she was the only one left to him. And he guarded her for good. He allowed Jon to go to her alone just because he knew she loved him, and he loved her and wouldn't harm her. But as we know, Jon was the one to take her life.

The reason why Drogon didn't harm Jon is that he knew his mother loved Jon, and wouldn't see him harmed. 
The other reason was that Jon had Targayren  blood and dragons have been ridden by Targayrens for centuries. So he did not dare kill one of his own.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [script](https://winteriscoming.net/2019/08/01/iron-throne-script-gives-little-insight-bran-chosen-king/?fbclid=IwAR3ptIBJayV6UBo1nidQNwL_VKg-QfWuP4o3c2ulg58nskaF7kXsu5xOm4w), Drogon did intentionally spare Jon, but the Iron Throne was just collateral damage as part of his rampage.

> He looks down at Jon. We see the fire build up in his throat.
>
> Jon sees it as well. He prepares to die.
>
> But the blast is not for him. **Drogon wants to burn the world** but he
>   will not kill Jon.
>
> He breathes fire on the back wall, blasting down what remains of the
>   great red blocks of stone. **We look over Jon’s shoulder as the fire
>   sweeps toward the throne– not the target of Drogon’s wrath, just a
>   dumb bystander caught up in the conflagration.**
>
> We look through the blades of the throne as the flames engulf it, and
>   blast the wall behind it.

However, just as Daeron's answer states, that doesn't mean that despite Drogon is NOT consciously aware of its symbolism, that it wasn't symbolically written this way for the story's benefit.