# Why didn't Drogon attack this character?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In extension to this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100891/why-did-drogon-do-this) about *Game of Thrones* S08E06, why did Drogon leave Jon after the death of Drogon's mother? Drogon had consciousness to destroy the Iron Throne.

We all know that Drogon allowed Jon to pet. Does Drogon have the consciousness to forgive as well or doesn't Drogon know who killed the Mother of Dragons?

Comment: Remember that Jon is also a Targaryen and the Dragons are able to sense this. There is clearly some sort of mental connection between them

Comment: Maybe it agreed with what Jon did. Drogon itself couldn't accept what its mother commanded it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He did not know whether it was Jon or not. He just saw her lying there and Jon mourning her death. He might have just thought that someone else did it. We do not know how intelligent the dragons are and whether they can deduct beyond the pure visible.

Answer (score 14):

I lean towards Leven's theory, but as an alternative I propose:

Drogon knew there was something wrong with Dany and that it was best that she die.  So he grieves for the loss of his rider and "mother", but does not punish the man who did what needed to be done.  He may have even melted the throne specifically as his last act to help "break the wheel", communicating the idea that heritage and birthright to the throne are now lost; that Jon in particular is not automatically the rightful ruler, and something new must be built.

Answer (score 10):

Dragons clearly have an unspoken connection to the Targaryens. Jon is a true Targaryen by birth. Jon and Dany are the only people we've seen ride dragons, and history tells us that only Targaryens can ride dragons.

Drogon recognizes Jon as a Targaryen, so he allows him to enter the remains of the Red Keep. He probably didn't know what Jon would do, but as a Targaryen, Drogon couldn't stand in his way.

When Drogon realized that Dany was dead, he was obviously furious. He may have even wanted to kill Jon. But in the end, he realized that Jon was the only living Targaryen, and couldn't kill him. Apparently a great-uncle was better than nothing.

Comment: Dragons can and have killed Targaryens. Furthermore, Targaryens are not the only ones who can ride dragons, All Valyrians can. In fact Targaryens were the smallest of the Dragonriding Freeholder Houses of Valyria. Dragons share their riders' friends and enemies. If Daenerys to her last moment thought of Jon as a friend, Drogon will consider him a friend as well. If Daenerys thought him an enemy......Well good luck Jonno.

Comment: Also, since we know that after a skinchanger dies a part of them goes on to live in their beast. While the bond between a rider and a dragon is extremely mysterious, it is possible that it is akin to skinchaning and some part of Daenerys was still alive in Drogon at that very moment.

Comment: @Aegon you make some really good points. post that as an answer and I'd vote for it

Comment: I am okay with it if you edit it in your existing answer. Not posting it as an answer because that's all based on books canon, not show canon.

Comment: @Aegon Do we know that to be true in the show universe, though?  Is anyone other than a Targaryen said to be capable of riding and bonding with a Dragon?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy The show begins in 300 AC so It's safe to assume that for all the events before that, the show and the books are on the same page. There are plenty of Non-Targaryen dragonriders in the books. It's just that we know Targaryens the best since they survived the doom. Well Targaryens and Velaryons although Velaryon dragonriders were far fewer. We have also had bastards of Houses Targaryen, Velaryon and Celtigar fly dragons. But on the off-chance that show has created it's own pre-S01E01 canon, this is posted as a comment rather than answer

Comment: @Aegon That doesn't follow at all.  If the show has never mentioned non-Targaryen riders (bastards or otherwise), then there's nothing to suppose that non-Targaryen riders even exist within the show.  And there are events that predate the start of the show that are depicted within the show and are different from those in the books (the prophecy given to Cersei, for example).

Comment: Even if there are other dragon-riders in the world, we haven't seen any in the show, and there's no indication that Drogon has ever encountered them. It's reasonable to assume that Drogon thinks Jon is the last of the Targaryens and the last of the dragon-riders.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy And that is what I said. The reason I am not making it an answer is because I don't know if it happens in the show that way and I simply don't care enough to look up all the different roads that the show took. FWIW, I was talking about grand history, Cersei's prophecy barely qualifies as that. I was not talking about smaller stuff like Cersei's prophecy or countless other minor changes, but rather the things that were grand in scale, i.e. Dance of the Dragons, Fall of Valyra, Valyrian Freehold.

Comment: Aegon has an amazing knowledge on GoT, he is like a dictionary for GoT in stackexchange. He's letting others to answer thats why he doesn't post answer. Also, you guys can look at his sci-fi profile.

Comment: _"Apparently a great-uncle was better than nothing."_ Dany is Jon's aunt, so Jon would be Drogon's cousin.

Answer (score 5):

In-universe it's unclear if we can attest Drogon either a full consciousness of the events or just a magical intuition for what's right. It doesn't exactly matter if his intelligence is more of a conscious, universal or emotional nature. But ultimately what matters is that ***he* realized what was really going on and that the "wheel" is ultimately at fault and needs to be broken**. So yes, he doesn't particularly like that his mother is dead, but neither does Jon afterall. But they both realize that it needed to be done.

And I think you can go even further than this. The **dragon as this enigmatic and majestic creature is actually necessary for exerting this ultimate act of reason** on the world and doing what Dany as a mere mortal is unable to do, not just physically but generally. While the story is primarily a political drama, it was always expected that the more **otherwordly factors of *Game of Thrones* are what ultimately has to call the humans to reason** in their useless struggle for power. And in fact, the only major thing I was really disappointed about this last season was the way in which they shoved the White Walker threat out of the way seemingly prematurely, because of the above expectations that they were necessary for "breaking the wheel".

So it was somewhat of a relief to see, if not the Ice, then at least the **Fire to rise above the human characters and stand in for what is the only right thing to do**, no matter if it did so conciously or merely out of an intuitive feel for universal justice as part of its magical nature.

And in the same way it's notable that this is a level of elevation noone really gave these creatures credit for, not Dany for whom they were her children but also largely weapons, nor Jon who expected Drogon to kill him as much as us viewers, until we all realized that they are ultimately above us and quite simply *out of this world*.

Comment: +1 Very intuitive. Something similar is also written here- _dragons appear to have some sort of higher, unnatural level of intelligence; they seem to be more in tune with the workings of the universe (i.e. "magic" or "fate" or "nature") than humans are, and possess a sense of mental awareness that humans do not._ Also, _Drogon melting the Iron Throne hinted that he understood something deeper than the scene suggested_ [Source: https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Dragons#Intelligence]

Answer (score 1):

Agree somewhat with Kami Kaze. My theory, which does not entail much calculating consciousness: He didn't see her get murdered, so the familiar Targaryen in the room was merely a neutral, protected presence. However, he was sad and angry, and so vented on the nearest available big thing.